# How node-red interact with ActiveMQ?

Tags: node-red

I want to do an example, consume data from the ActiveMQ queue, and also can generate data into the ActiveMQ queue, but I have not found a suitable solution, I need everyone's help.

Comment: What have you done to find a suitable solution? What did you find, and why was it not suitable?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read the doc on what a good question needs https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes. I have found a solution. It was my own misconfiguration.